# Admin Consent dialog requests different permissions then requested

Tags: c#, azure, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-web

I'm developing a asp.net core .net 5 web app hosted in azure and I want to provide SSO experience to our customers.

As a reference, I took the example from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant where an AAD administrator grants permissions to the app for all users in the AAD.

The example makes use of the Admin consent url described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin

In my case, I just want to enable the users log in with their company account and read their email after log in (no other profile data). So I thought requesting the scopes "openid" and "email" would be sufficient. But it doesn't matter what scope value I provide, the dialog presented to the administrator shows other permission requests (looks like "profile" and "offline_access" (?)):

[image]

I build the url like this:

```
var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(
   httpContext.Request.Scheme,
   httpContext.Request.Host,
   httpContext.Request.PathBase);

var authorizationRequest = string.Format(
   "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id={0}&scope={1}&redirect_uri={2}&state={3}", 
   Uri.EscapeDataString(this.microsoftIdentityOptions.ClientId),   
   Uri.EscapeDataString("openid email"),                           
   Uri.EscapeDataString(currentUri + "tenant/processcode"),        
   Uri.EscapeDataString(state));
```

The resulting request looks like this:
[image]

Funny thing is if the administrator grants access to the app and if I check the permissions of the "enterprise application" in AAD, I see exactly the "email" and "openid" permissions I initially wanted:
[image]

But this is very confusing for the AAD administrator and I really want to present a dialog matching my permission requests.

Comment: The offline access permission can mean that you are getting a refresh token. The profile one looks a bit weird - as if it was showing consent to profile even though you request only the email in the ID token. I think this is something you should ask Microsoft's support.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain these two points:

1. This is a known issue. When you use the v2.0 endpoint, even if you don't add the offline_access scope, it will still be displayed in the admin consent page, and it cannot be deleted currently. The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access) also explains this.

> This permission currently appears on all consent pages, even for flows
> that don't provide a refresh token (such as the implicit flow). This
> setup addresses scenarios where a client can begin within the implicit
> flow and then move to the code flow where a refresh token is expected.

If you don't want the offline_access scope to appear in the initial admin consent page, you can use the v1.0 endpoint. (However, the 1.0 endpoint can only request static permissions)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={0}&scope={1}&redirect_uri={2}&state={3}
```

2. If the application uses OpenID Connect to log in, it must request the `openid` scope. The `openid` scope includes the `profile` scope by default, which is by design! The scope of `openid` is explained on the admin consent page as: **Allows users to sign in to the app with their work or school accounts and allows the app to see basic user profile information.**

[image]

Comment: If my reply is helpful, you can accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

by default, as shown [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs), the client will ask for the openid and profile:

```
        Scope.Add("openid");
        Scope.Add("profile");
```

Thats why you typically see the call to Clear(), to clear this default list of Scopes, like:

```
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("myscope");
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried resetting the scope in the method `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>  this.configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
 options.Scope.Clear();
 options.Scope.Add("openid");
 options.Scope.Add("email");` but, it did not change the dialog

Comment: one idea is to look at the initial authentication request and verify that the expected scopes are sent to the identity provider.

Comment: I updated my question with an image of the initial authentication request build. There I can see only the 2 scopes "openid" and "email" being requested.

Comment: i think its up to the implementer of the identity provider to do as they like and in your case perhaps they always include the profile? alternatively, you could add your identity provider, like IdentityServer in the middle if you wan t more control over the login experience